# Aeson match binary tree

Tags: haskell, binary-tree, aeson

I am having a hard time trying to parse a structure like

```
{"tree": [5, [[1, 4], [2, 3]]]}
```

into a binary tree

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

but I can’t even seem to get the types right. Is there a simple solution to this problem?

I assume that each JSON array contains exactly two elements, so the outcome should be

```
Node (Leaf 5) (Node (Node (Leaf 1) (Leaf 4)) (Node (Leaf 2) (Leaf 3))) :: Tree Int
```

**Edit:** What I have tried:

I tried adding a new data type for importing

```
data IntTree = IntTree { jsonTree :: Tree Int }

instance FromJSON IntTree
  where
    parseJSON (Object v) = do
        inttree <- (v .: "tree")
        -- now I am stuck
```

Comment: The return value of `v .: "tree"` is going to be `FromJSON a => Parser a`, so anything that has a `FromJSON` instance can be returned.  Specifically, you want it to be a 2-tuple or a 2 element list.  Luckily, there's an instance of `(FromJSON a, FromJSON b) => FromJSON (a, b)` already defined, so you can use aeson's features to handle what happens when the length of the list is not 2.  I'm assuming this tree can't just be a `Leaf`, i.e. `{"tree": 1}`, so you can do `(left, right) <- v .: "tree"` to get the top two values.  What would you do after this point?

Comment: A single `Leaf` should also work so I would have to match for both `(l, r)` and `leaf`. Not sure how to do this matching in a do expression.

Comment: then it's probably going be easier to work with the json Value type directly. I would write a function that transforms a Value tree into your Tree type, then use that inside parseJSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I started using Aeson I found the `FromJSON` and `ToJSON` types useful but didn't really understand how they worked. I found that messing about with the [underlying  types that Aeson uses to represent JSON values](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.8.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html) can be quite educational. For example, it uses `HashMap` for objects and `Vector` for arrays:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as H
import qualified Data.Vector as V

j = "{\"tree\": [5, [[1, 4], [2, 3]]]}"

data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show)

Just (Object decoded) = decode j :: Maybe Value

Just tree = H.lookup "tree" decoded

parse :: FromJSON a => Value -> Tree a
parse t = case t of
    Array v -> if V.length v /= 2
                   then error "Not a binary tree"
                   else Node (parse (V.head v)) (parse (V.last v))
    x       -> Leaf $ case fromJSON x of
                   Success a   -> a
                   Error   msg -> error msg


main = print $ show $ (parse tree :: Tree Int)
```